# How to consume a simple Restful service with Scala and Akka-Http 10.0.5

Tags: json, scala, rest, unmarshalling, akka-http

I spent a whole day figuring out how to

1. Consume a remote restful json service
2. Unmarshall (deserialize) the payload into a case class model

The guys over at the google plus Akka mailing list were very helpful, so I thought it would be nice to have a working example on SO as well, for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Akka-Http 10.0.5

---

```
package xxx

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, FlatSpec, MustMatchers}
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives

case class ColorBlob(url: String, averageColor: String, classificationColor: String)
case class ColorBlobsResponse(colorBlobs: Map[String, Option[ColorBlob]])

trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
   implicit val format1 = jsonFormat3(ColorBlob)
   implicit val format2 = jsonFormat1(ColorBlobsResponse)
}

class ColorBlobRestTest
   extends FlatSpec
   with MockitoSugar
   with BeforeAndAfter
   with MustMatchers
   with ScalaFutures
   with JsonSupport
   with Directives {

   implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
   implicit val executor: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
   implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

   "this" should "work" in {
       val request = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET, uri = s"https://colorservice/colorblobs/en?productCodes=904655")
       val futureResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(request)

       val futureColorBlobResponse: Future[ColorBlobsResponse] = futureResponse.flatMap { response: HttpResponse =>
           val entity: ResponseEntity = response.entity
           Unmarshal(entity).to[ColorBlobsResponse]
       }

       import scala.concurrent.duration._
       val colorBlobsResponse: ColorBlobsResponse = Await.result(futureColorBlobResponse, 1000.millis)

       assert(1==1)

    }
}
```

Comment: What are the dependencies to be added ? Do you have any github projects for the same ?

Comment: just saw our post, have you figured it out in mean time?